# Как синхронизировать пользователей из Github/G-Suit в openLDAP?

Tags: linux, github, ssh, ldap

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли решение для синхронизации пользователей из Github организации и G-Suit в openLDAP.

В результате нужно получит возможность авторизации по SSH (в будущем возможно RDP) участников организации Github/G-Suit

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста: *g-suit* — это защитная плёнка или костюм для лётчиков?

Comment: Google Apps for Work — пакет облачных служб и приложений для совместной работы, предлагаемый компанией Google по подписке.